# What is a lifespan of a State object in a big picture?

Tags: flutter, navigation

I understand that the `State` object is tightly connected with its `StatefulElement` and that they're both disposed when the element tree changes so much, that they're not there anymore.

But let's assume that we code quite a big app with around 80 screens. And I navigate throughout the app, adding new pages to the navigation stack, some of them keep the `State`. Stack of pages has already 30 screens. I go to another app, have to check something on Google Maps, call mum, but in the end I want to go back to our app to fill in the long form with the data I've just got from my mum. Unfortunately, to get back to the form I have to go back a screen or a few.

My question is: can I expect some of the 30 pages to be removed from the memory so far, but others not?

I guess no. I guess:

- or I lose all of pages and its States (eg. due to a single Android Activity kill),
- or I still have got all the pages (and States)

I'm looking for a confirmation cause I couldn't find one.

Comment: if the physical process was killed all your ephemeral state variables will be lost - if you want to do something with that use [RestorationMixin](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/RestorationMixin-mixin.html)

Comment: I know, but my question is not about how to handle the ephemeral state. It's about the nature of the ephemeral state.